# Customize IdentityUserRole in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

In my asp dotnet core application, I'm changing the default `IdentityUser` and the `IdentityRole` into my own classes `MesUser` and `MesRole`

```
public class MesUser : IdentityUser<int>, IUser
{
    #region Property

    /// <summary>
    /// Osobní číslo
    /// </summary>
    [Column("ID")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Křestní jméno
    /// </summary>
    [Column("FIRST_NAME")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and set it in dbcontext

```
public DbSet<MesUser> MesUsers { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<MesUser>().ToTable("COR_USERS").HasKey(t => t.Id);
```

but if I do something similar with any other Identity class I get error message:

> A key cannot be configured on 'MesRoleUser' because it is a derived
>   type. The key must be configured on the root type
>   'IdentityUserRole'. If you did not intend for
>   'IdentityUserRole' to be included in the model, ensure that it is
>   not included in a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a
>   configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation
>   property on a type that is included in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I know that just a link is not the rule but by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) you will learn:

- how to change user key type,

  - in particular you do not need to override members
- that changing the key type for user in identity involves changes in many classes.